# SharePoint 2016 PowerPivot Management Dashboard not showing Workbook Activity List Data

Tags: powerpivot

Does anyone know what is required to get the 'Workbook Activity - List' webpart on the PowerPivot Management dashboard returning data? I assume it should be pointing at the Workbook Activity workbook that ships with SP2016 in PowerPivot Management library in Central admin. I have followed Microsoft's documentation on connecting the Workbook Activity spreadsheet to the PowerPivot Management Data workbook and I have data successfully loaded in both workbooks but nothing in the web part on the Dashboard. Any ideas?

[image: PowerPivot Management Dashbaord]